# "database.sql is a dump of the PostgreSQL database. It needs to be restored."

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a Django site running with PSQL but when my friend gave the site back to me he said: "database.sql is a dump of the database. It needs to be restored."

What does this mean?

Comment: What about if you ask your friend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that `database.sql` has the database storage information of your sites data. You may restore it in your postgresql database by:

```
psql dbname < infile
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/backup.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE

Comment: My original post was edited by a mod to remove the word "newb" (thanks) but yeah I'm a newb. I load up the SQL shell but I'm not sure what to do after that.